# Arduino Cloud Light -- Boolean thunderstorm

Tags: boolean, arduino, light

I'm using an arduino to make a Cloud Light with an IR remote. I am trying to make one of the buttons simulate a thunder storm where the white LED's will randomly flash WITHIN the boolean statement under the specific code... Trouble is, I can only make it go through the flash period once... Here's the portion of code for the storm:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
// My modified code
int RECV_PIN = 11;
int red = 2;
int yellow = 3;
int green = 4;
int blue = 5;
int purple = 6;
int white = 7;
long randOn = random(10,200);
long guess = random(1000,20000);

#define powercode 16726725
#define stormcode 4294967295                   




IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);
          pinMode(purple, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(white, OUTPUT);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}


int redbool = 0;
int orangebool = 0;
int yellowbool = 0;
int greenbool = 0;
int bluebool = 0;
int purplebool = 0;
int whitebool = 0;
int rgbbool = 0;
int rainbowbool = 0;
int sunbool = 0;
int rainbool = 0;
int stormbool = 0;
int quickbool = 0;

unsigned long last = millis();

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {


//Sun

    if (results.value == 16726725) { 
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        sunbool = !sunbool;
        if (sunbool == 0) {
          digitalWrite (red, LOW);
          digitalWrite (yellow, LOW);
          digitalWrite (green, LOW);
          digitalWrite (blue, LOW);
          digitalWrite (purple, LOW);
          digitalWrite (white, LOW);
        }
      else { 
          digitalWrite (red, LOW);
          digitalWrite (green, LOW);
          digitalWrite (blue, LOW);
          digitalWrite (purple, LOW);

          digitalWrite (white, HIGH);
          digitalWrite (yellow, HIGH);
          }
      }
      last = millis();
    }

 //rain

    if (results.value == 16745085) { 
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        rainbool = !rainbool;
        if (rainbool == 0) {
          digitalWrite (red, LOW);
          digitalWrite (yellow, LOW);
          digitalWrite (green, LOW);
          digitalWrite (blue, LOW);
          digitalWrite (purple, LOW);
          digitalWrite (white, LOW);
        }
      else { 
          digitalWrite (red, LOW);
          digitalWrite (green, LOW);
          digitalWrite (yellow, LOW);
          digitalWrite (purple, LOW);

          digitalWrite (white, HIGH);
          digitalWrite (blue, HIGH);
          }
      }
      last = millis();
    }   
//storm

    if (results.value == 16759365) { 
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        stormbool = !stormbool;
        if (stormbool == 0) {
          digitalWrite (red, LOW);
          digitalWrite (yellow, LOW);
          digitalWrite (green, LOW);
          digitalWrite (blue, HIGH);
          digitalWrite (purple, HIGH);
          digitalWrite (white, LOW);
        }
      else { 
          digitalWrite (red, LOW);
          digitalWrite (green, LOW);
          digitalWrite (yellow, LOW);
          digitalWrite (white, LOW);

          digitalWrite (blue, HIGH);
          digitalWrite (purple, HIGH);

   digitalWrite(white, HIGH);  
   delay(randOn);  
   digitalWrite(white, LOW);   
   delay(randOn + randOn);  
   digitalWrite(white, HIGH);  
   delay(randOn);    
   digitalWrite(white, LOW); 
          }
      }
      last = millis();
    }
 //rainbow
        if (results.value == 16712445) { // TIVO button
      // If it's been at least 1/4 second since the last
      // IR received, toggle the relay
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        rainbowbool = !rainbowbool;
        digitalWrite(white, LOW);
        digitalWrite(red, rainbowbool ? HIGH : LOW);
                digitalWrite(yellow, rainbowbool ? HIGH : LOW);
                        digitalWrite(green, rainbowbool ? HIGH : LOW);
                                digitalWrite(blue, rainbowbool ? HIGH : LOW);
                                        digitalWrite(purple, rainbowbool ? HIGH : LOW);


      }
      last = millis();
    }   

 //red
        if (results.value == 16718565) { // TIVO button
      // If it's been at least 1/4 second since the last
      // IR received, toggle the relay
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        redbool = !redbool;
        digitalWrite(red, redbool ? HIGH : LOW);
      }
      last = millis();
    }
//orange
    if (results.value == 16726215) { // TIVO button
      // If it's been at least 1/4 second since the last
      // IR received, toggle the relay
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        orangebool = !orangebool;
        digitalWrite(red, orangebool ? HIGH : LOW);
        digitalWrite(yellow, orangebool ? HIGH : LOW);
      }
      last = millis();
    }
//yellow
    if (results.value == 16718055) { // TIVO button
      // If it's been at least 1/4 second since the last
      // IR received, toggle the relay
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        yellowbool = !yellowbool;
        digitalWrite(yellow, yellowbool ? HIGH : LOW);
      }
      last = millis();
    }
//green
    if (results.value == 16751205) { // TIVO button
      // If it's been at least 1/4 second since the last
      // IR received, toggle the relay
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        greenbool = !greenbool;
        digitalWrite(green, greenbool ? HIGH : LOW);
      }
      last = millis();
    }
//blue
    if (results.value == 16753245) { // TIVO button
      // If it's been at least 1/4 second since the last
      // IR received, toggle the relay
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        bluebool = !bluebool;
        digitalWrite(blue, bluebool ? HIGH : LOW);
      }
      last = millis();
    }
//purple
    if (results.value == 16757325) { // TIVO button
      // If it's been at least 1/4 second since the last
      // IR received, toggle the relay
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        purplebool = !purplebool;
        digitalWrite(purple, purplebool ? HIGH : LOW);
      }
      last = millis();
    }
//white
    if (results.value == 16720605) { // TIVO button
      // If it's been at least 1/4 second since the last
      // IR received, toggle the relay
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
        whitebool = !whitebool;
        digitalWrite(white, whitebool ? HIGH : LOW);
      }
      last = millis();
            }
        //Quick section
        if (results.value == 16771095) { // TIVO button
      // If it's been at least 1/4 second since the last
      // IR received, toggle the relay
      if (millis() - last > 250) {
          quickbool =! quickbool;

            digitalWrite(white, HIGH);  
           delay(guess);  
           digitalWrite(white, LOW);   
           delay(guess);  
           digitalWrite(white, HIGH);  
           delay(guess + guess);    
           digitalWrite(white, LOW); 

      }

      last = millis();
    }
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }


}
```

If I keep adding these delays and digitalWrites, I can't change "channels" or LED's to different colors, I'm stuck until the thing finishes! Thanks for helping me ahead of time!

Comment: Can you please post all your code or explain what each variable is? Are you 100% it is just in *this* part? It may be something that changes the variable. If you do post all your code, try to explain how to inference to your remote and show your circuits so we can help you. We can't help you without everything. :) One more thing, when you pick out your tags, hover over them to make sure they are what you want. When you hover over `lightning`, it says: `Questions about the Lightning extension to Mozilla Thunderbird`.

Comment: Wait... where's your entire code?

Comment: Sorry, I am wrestling with this new "insert code properly" message. Haha, I am really new here which is pretty obvious. Thanks a lot of the tips, everything is helpful! Also, the //Quick Section is where I'm tooling with fixing the problem in the //Storm part of the code

Comment: Sure. A couple of things: 1.) You need to remove the "cloud" tag. 2.) Don't forget to click the little check mark by an answer if it is your "accepted" answer to verify it works.

Answer (score 0):

you are correct that when using the delay function no other action can happen. You should try and make your code like the [blinkWithoutDelay](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) example.
so you could do something like this

```
// struct that represents the values for each led
struct LED{
  int pin; // pin # the led is connected to
  int state; // state of the led , on or off
  long interval; // how long we should wait before toggling
  long timeToggled; // last time we toggled
};

if(results.value == 16759365){
  digitalWrite(0,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(2,HIGH); 

  LED white = {0,HIGH,100,millis()}; 
  LED yellow = {1,HIGH,10,millis()};
  LED blue = {2,HIGH,420,millis()};

  results = readIr(); // check the ir value again and keep looping until it changes
  while(results.value == 16759365){
     toggleLed(white);
     toggleLed(yellow);
     toggleLed(blue);
     results = readIr(); // if ir value hasnt changed keep looping until it does
  }

  digitalWrite(0,LOW);
  digitalWrite(1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(2,LOW);
}



void toggleLed(struct LED currentLed){
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - currentLed.timeToggled > currentLed.interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED 
    currentLed.timeToggled = currentMillis;   

    // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
    if (currentLed.state == LOW)
      currentLed.state = HIGH;
    else
      currentLed.state = LOW;

    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    digitalWrite(currentLed.pin, currentLed.state);
  }
}
```

Comment: now that you have posted the full code that changes things since you are checking for change in the void loop function, so you wouldn't need the while loop, but you should be able to get an idea from the sample i posted